# Initialising stored procedure/function from sequelize.query() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Here is my stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetAllEmployee()
RETURNS setof "Employees" AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
select * from "Employees";
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I am trying to call it from my route like this

```
    sequelize.sync().then(function() {

    app.get("/sp", (req, res) => {
        try {
            sequelize.query("GetAllEmployee()").then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    });

});
```

But I keep getting this error message

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near    "GetAllEmployee"
```

Comment: Does the procedure already stored in database? Does it works when you call it from some SQL interface that you can see the query results? Also, which db you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 'CALL' before the SP name.

Also you probably forgot to add an OUT parameter in your SP.

here's a demo code:

```js
sequelize.query('SET @outputData = null; CALL stored_procedure (:someInputData, @outputData); SELECT @outputData;',
    {
      replacements: {
        someInputData: 'Send Your Data Here',
      },
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW,
    })
    .spread(response => console.log(response, 'response'))
    .error((error) => {
      console.log(error, 'errored');
    });
```

Note: add 'multipleStatements: true' to your sequelize config while creating instance, like so:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database.dbName, config.database.username, config.database.password,
  {
    host: config.database.host,
    dialect: config.database.dialect,
    logging: false,
    dialectOptions: {
      multipleStatements: true,
    },
  });
```